# How to call a method for every page?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm writing an application using Spring MVC.
I have a method that returns values from a database. And I want to display these values in the site's header (which is shown on all pages). How I can do this?

I need to call this method in every controller.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare a class with `@ControllerAdvice` annotation, then declare a method with `@ModelAttribute` annotation. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute
  public void myMethod(Model model) {

    Object myValues = // obtain your data from DB here...

    model.addAttribute("myDbValues", myValues);
  }
}
```

Spring MVC will invoke this method before each method in each MVC controller. You will be able to use the `myDbValues` attribute in all pages.

The `@ControllerAdvice` class should be in the same Java namespace where all your MVC controllers are (to make sure Spring can detect it automatically).

See the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for more details on `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ModelAttribute` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).