# Add User Object to every request and response

Tags: spring-mvc

What can be the approach to append the user object in every request and response in Spring MVC 3.
So that on the Jsp if I do the request.getAttribute("user"), then I should be able to get the User Object.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Store user object in session. or @SessionAttribute("user")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`User` object in a session attribute**

You can put your `User` object in a session attribute:

```
@Controller
public class MyMvcController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        User user = ... // initialise your User object here
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

If you put the `User` object in a session attribute, it will be stored on the server between HTTP requests, so you need to initialize it only once somewhere in your application.

In JSP, you can access the `User` object with `session.getAttribute("user")`, or with EL: `${user.id}`, `${user.name}`...

**`User` object in an MVC model**

Alternatively, if you do not want to store your object in the session attributes, you can create a new `User` object in every request and put it in your MVC model as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697207/2842067):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute
  public void myMethod(Model model) {

    User user = // initialise your User object here
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

  }
}
```

See the original answer for details.

In JSP, you can access the `User` object with `request.getAttribute("user")`, or with EL: `${user.id}`, `${user.name}`...

Answer (score 0):

You want User object in every request and response.

```
  @Controller
  @SessionAttribute("user")
  public class UserController{

  }
```

JSP code:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user">...</form:form>
```

You can use that user object as you want:

```
${user.name}  //equivalent to request.getAttribute("user").getName();
${user.age}
```